# Java Label disappear

Tags: java, label, frame

I want to make a simple agenda but somehow when I run the compiler it doesn't load the label's text and sometimes it does. How do i fix this?

example:
(can't show pictures)

1. 13:00pm(this is what always shows up) Course A
2. 13:30pm Course b

and sometimes it does this:

1. 13:00pm(always shows up) (then nothing)
2. 13:30pm

(please keep it simple cause I am a beginner and from The Netherlands).

CODE:
(I am a beginner so don't look at that copy and paste stuff)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class P{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(" Agenda 10/13/2014");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(620,620);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    JLabel labeltime1 = new JLabel("1:00 - 1:30pm: ");
    JLabel labeltime2 = new JLabel("1:30 - 2:00pm: ");
    JLabel labeltime3 = new JLabel("2:00 - 2:30pm: ");
    JLabel labeltime4 = new JLabel("2:30 - 3:00pm: ");
    JLabel labeltime5 = new JLabel("3:00 - 3:30pm: ");

    labeltime1.setForeground(Color.red);
    labeltime2.setForeground(Color.red);
    labeltime3.setForeground(Color.red);
    labeltime4.setForeground(Color.red);
    labeltime5.setForeground(Color.red);

    JLabel space1 = new JLabel("\n");
    JLabel space2 = new JLabel("\n");
    JLabel space3 = new JLabel("\n");
    JLabel space4 = new JLabel("\n");
    JLabel space5 = new JLabel("\n");

    JPanel timeP = new JPanel();
    timeP.setBackground(Color.black);
    timeP.setLayout(new BoxLayout(timeP, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    timeP.add(space5);
    timeP.add(labeltime1);
    timeP.add(space1);
    timeP.add(labeltime2);
    timeP.add(space2);
    timeP.add(labeltime3);
    timeP.add(space3);
    timeP.add(labeltime4);
    timeP.add(space4);
    timeP.add(labeltime5);

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, timeP);

    JPanel courses = new JPanel();
    courses.setLayout(new BoxLayout(courses, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    courses.setBackground(Color.black);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,courses);

    //Enter your course
    JLabel course1 = new JLabel(" Course A");
    JLabel course2 = new JLabel(" Course B");
    JLabel course3 = new JLabel(" Course C");
    JLabel course4 = new JLabel(" Course D");
    JLabel course5 = new JLabel(" Course E");

    course1.setForeground(Color.yellow);
    course2.setForeground(Color.yellow);
    course3.setForeground(Color.yellow);
    course4.setForeground(Color.yellow);
    course5.setForeground(Color.yellow);

    JLabel space6 = new JLabel("\n");
    JLabel space7 = new JLabel("\n");
    JLabel space8 = new JLabel("\n");
    JLabel space9 = new JLabel("\n");
    JLabel space10 = new JLabel("\n");

    courses.add(space6);
    courses.add(course1);
    courses.add(space7);
    courses.add(course2);
    courses.add(space8);
    courses.add(course3);
    courses.add(space9);
    courses.add(course4);
    courses.add(space10);
    courses.add(course5);


}
```

}

Comment: you want us to debug your UI code without code or images of the UI?

Comment: I don't think its the problem of the code, its really weird.

Comment: 13:00pm what is that

Comment: I can guarantee you it's a problem with the code.

Comment: It seems you are dynamically populate missing label or your container might hide that label in some case. Can you please post some code ?

Comment: I never had it before, and getlost i wrote it wrong i mixed dutch time with English time lol

Comment: ok i put some code down wait a sec

Comment: move `frame.setVisible(true);` to lastline

Comment: ok thanks, I am gonna try

Comment: thank you, it worked (I was wrong)

Answer (score 1):

moving `frame.setVisible(true);` to lastline will fix your problem.you need to call setvisible after you add component .or you can call repaint(),revalidate();

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class P{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(" Agenda 10/13/2014");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(620,620);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        //frame.setVisible(true);//don't call this method here

    JLabel labeltime1 = new JLabel("1:00 - 1:30pm: ");
    JLabel labeltime2 = new JLabel("1:30 - 2:00pm: ");
    JLabel labeltime3 = new JLabel("2:00 - 2:30pm: ");
    JLabel labeltime4 = new JLabel("2:30 - 3:00pm: ");
    JLabel labeltime5 = new JLabel("3:00 - 3:30pm: ");

    labeltime1.setForeground(Color.red);
    labeltime2.setForeground(Color.red);
    labeltime3.setForeground(Color.red);
    labeltime4.setForeground(Color.red);
    labeltime5.setForeground(Color.red);

    JLabel space1 = new JLabel("\n");
    JLabel space2 = new JLabel("\n");
    JLabel space3 = new JLabel("\n");
    JLabel space4 = new JLabel("\n");
    JLabel space5 = new JLabel("\n");

    JPanel timeP = new JPanel();
    timeP.setBackground(Color.black);
    timeP.setLayout(new BoxLayout(timeP, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    timeP.add(space5);
    timeP.add(labeltime1);
    timeP.add(space1);
    timeP.add(labeltime2);
    timeP.add(space2);
    timeP.add(labeltime3);
    timeP.add(space3);
    timeP.add(labeltime4);
    timeP.add(space4);
    timeP.add(labeltime5);

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, timeP);

    JPanel courses = new JPanel();
    courses.setLayout(new BoxLayout(courses, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    courses.setBackground(Color.black);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,courses);

    //Enter your course
    JLabel course1 = new JLabel(" Course A");
    JLabel course2 = new JLabel(" Course B");
    JLabel course3 = new JLabel(" Course C");
    JLabel course4 = new JLabel(" Course D");
    JLabel course5 = new JLabel(" Course E");

    course1.setForeground(Color.yellow);
    course2.setForeground(Color.yellow);
    course3.setForeground(Color.yellow);
    course4.setForeground(Color.yellow);
    course5.setForeground(Color.yellow);

    JLabel space6 = new JLabel("\n");
    JLabel space7 = new JLabel("\n");
    JLabel space8 = new JLabel("\n");
    JLabel space9 = new JLabel("\n");
    JLabel space10 = new JLabel("\n");

    courses.add(space6);
    courses.add(course1);
    courses.add(space7);
    courses.add(course2);
    courses.add(space8);
    courses.add(course3);
    courses.add(space9);
    courses.add(course4);
    courses.add(space10);
    courses.add(course5);
    frame.setVisible(true);//call here

}

}
```